# Is seeing the fire a requirement for havdala?

Tags: shabbat, see-sight-vision-blind, havdalah

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How seriously do we take the finger-inspection in Havdala?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13941/how-seriously-do-we-take-the-finger-inspection-in-havdala)

Is it necessary to see the fire for havdala? In shul, people usually crowd around whoever is holding the candle and I can't see it. Do I still have to hear havdalah again after that? (I hear it anyway because the rest of my family has to hear it, I'm just wondering if I need to.)

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13941/759

Comment: @ Double AA. Yeah. It's not exactly the same question but the answer to my question is there. Sorry

Comment: Close match, but not exact. This is whether you have to see the fire at all, not about the reflection in your fingernails.