# What are the customs for looking at fingers during havdalla

Tags: minhag, havdalah

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do with the candles during Havdalah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1869/what-to-do-with-the-candles-during-havdalah)

According to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13941/how-seriously-do-we-take-the-finger-inspection-in-havdala), there are many different customs about looking at fingers after the bracha *borei m'orei ha'eish* in havdalla. What are some of the different customs and what are the reasons for them?

Comment: See perek arvei pesachim which talks about this.

Comment: See pesachim 53b which discusses this and says since fire was first created on Motzei shabbas.we look at nails because Adam first realized that he was naked beside for his nails, and also to make the bracha.

Comment: see note 20 of Radal's commentary on Pirkei D'Rebbi Eliezer: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21858&st=&pgnum=123